# Shell Script - Awk Optimization

Tags: shell, awk

I am looking for some assistance in trying to optimize a bro network log parsing script, here's the background:

I have a large amount of bro logs, but I'm only interested in querying IPs within my scope (multiple variable length subnets).

So I have a text file with regex patterns to match the IP ranges I'm looking for:
scope.txt:

```
/^10\.0\.0\.([8-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])$/
```

(scope.txt contains up to 20 more lines of other IP ranges in regex patterns)
findInScope.sh:

```
#!bin/sh
for file in /data/bro_logs/2016-11-26/conn.*.log.gz
do
    echo "$file"
    touch /tmp/$file
    for nets in $(cat scope.txt)
    do
        echo "$nets"
        zcat $file | bro-cut -d | awk '$3 ~ '$nets' || $5 ~ '$nets'' >> /tmp/$file
    done
    sort /tmp/$file | uniq > ~/$file
    rm /tmp/$file
done
```

As more background, each hour of original bro conn logs is about 100MBs, so my current script takes about 10-20 minute to parse through one hour of log data.  One day of logs can take up to 3 hours.

I thought about a single awk statement with 40 or's but decided I don't want to do that because I want a separate scope.txt file in to use the same script for different scopes of IP ranges.

I also tried zcat on multiple conn.log files (i.e. zcat conn.*.log.gz) but the output file ended up being over 1GB, and I wanted to keep hourly logs intact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should gain a lot by passing the log file just once through awk. This means combining all the regexps into one. If you don't want to do this in your `scope.txt` file, then do it before calling awk. For example,

```
sed <scope.txt 's|^/\^|(|; s|\$/$|)|; $!s/$/|/' | tr -d '\n' >pattern

zcat $file | bro-cut -d |
awk '
BEGIN{ getline pat <"pattern"; pat = "^(" pat ")$" }
$3 ~ pat || $5 ~ pat
'  >~/$file
```

The sed replaces the `/^` and `$` surrounding each regexp line with a enclosing `()` pair, adds an `|` at the end of the line, and puts the result all on one line into file `pattern`. This file is therefore all the patterns or-ed together. The missing `^(...)$` is added in the awk script `BEGIN` statement, which reads the pattern file into variable `pat`.

The above replaces your inner `for` loop, and the `sort|uniq`.

Comment: Not quite; `^(one)|(two)|(three)|(four)$` only anchors one at the left, four at the right, and two and three not at all. You want `^(one|two|three|four)$` if all the individual patterns are anchored-both like the example given; otherwise leave the anchors (if present) within each alternative (unchanged) and don't add any.

Comment: @meuh & dave_thompson_085, thank you, I will be giving this a try at work this week.  Let you know how it goes.

Comment: @meuh thanks again, this worked for me with a bit of tweaking as cited by date_thompson_085.  I additionally ran my awks in parallel to parse through 8 file simultaneously and went from 5 hours to 15 minutes.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: You might gain a bit more cpu by moving the `bro-cut -d` out of the pipe, and doing it only on the final results. You'll need to copy a header onto the start of the output first.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to use `scope.txt`, very slightly modified, as a patternfile, and use `zcat | grep` (or just `zgrep`) to get the lines you need.

First, modify your `scope` file to change:

```
/^10\.0\.0\.([8-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])$/
```

into:

```
(^|[^0-9.])(10\.0\.0\.([8-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5]))($|[^0-9.])
```

To do this easily you can use:

```
sed -e 's:^/\^:(^|[^0-9.])(:' -e 's:\$/$:)($|[^0-9.]):' scope.txt > grepscope.txt
```

Then, do your search:

```
zgrep -Ehf grepscope.txt /data/bro_logs/2016-11-26/conn.*.log.gz | less
```

Or, since you want the output for each file stored separately:

```
for f in /data/bro_logs/2016-11-26/conn.*.log.gz; do
    zgrep -Ehf grepscope.txt "$f" | sort -u > ~/"${f##*/}"
done
```

---

Note also that the "for" loop variable `$f` will contain the *entire* path to each file in turn; to avoid the errors we would get if we tried to direct output to `~/"$f"` (which would refer to subdirectories `~/data/bro_logs/2016-11-26` that probably don't exist in your home directory), we strip off everything up to the final slash in the pathname and just use the base name of each log file.

---

The flags to `zgrep` bear mentioning:

`-E` specifies extended regex, so that the parentheses in your patterns don't need to be escaped.

`-h` suppresses printing the filename as a prefix to each matching line.  (You can omit this in the `for` loop version, since by default `grep` only prints the filename when searching more than one file, as in the first command I specified—but it doesn't hurt anything to keep it in both versions.)

`-f` allows you to **specify a patternfile.**  This is exactly what you need, according to your question, and using `grep -f` allows you to use multiple search patterns taken from a file, without constructing an Awk command with huge numbers of "or"s.

---

`sort | uniq` can generally be replaced by `sort -u`, unless you need to use some of `uniq`'s option flags.  In this case you don't, so I've used the simpler form `sort -u`.

Comment: @iruvar, thanks for the catch!  I was consulting a BSD `grep` man page (on OS X).  `grep -z` or `grep -Z` on BSD is equivalent to `zgrep` on Linux; however `zgrep` works in either place, so would be the preferred way to call for unzipping.  GNU `grep -z`, as you point out, modifies `grep`'s behavior to use null-delimiting input rather than newline delimited.  I've updated the answer to correct this.

Comment: thank you, this also looks like a great option, I will give this a try as well and let you know how it goes.

Comment: thanks again, I didn't end up going this route, I went with the sed / awk above as I'm more comfortable with that syntax.  I for sure feel there's more than one way to do this.